# What is builtins.object?

Tags: python

What is the meaning of `builtins.object` in the output?

```
class Fruits:
    p=12
    def __init__(self,name,color,taste):
        self.name=name
        self.color=color
        self.taste=taste
    def show(self):
        return f"Fruit name: {self.name}\nFruit color: {self.color}\nFruit taste: {self.taste}"
class Apple(Fruits):
    pass
obj1=Apple(3,3,3)
print(help(Apple))
```

Output:

```
Help on class Apple in module __main__:

class Apple(Fruits)
 |  Apple(name, color, taste)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Apple
 |      Fruits
 |      **builtins.object # What is the meaning of builtins.object?**
 |  
 |  Methods inherited from Fruits:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, name, color, taste)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  show(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Fruits:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from Fruits:
 |  
 |  p = 12
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object

Comment: `object` is the base for all classes. All classes inherit from it.

Comment: @TheThonnu please elaborate it a bit.. I am not getting you.

Comment: @AliMurtaza - answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` is the base for all classes. All classes inherit from it.

Essentially, it has a lot of default functions, like this:

```py
class object:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{type(self).__name__} object at 0x000000000000>'
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{type(self).__name__} object at 0x000000000000>'
```

And when you define a class, `class Foo:`, it is equivalent to saying `class Foo(object):`

All classess inherit these default functions from `object`.

When it shows this in `help`

```
Method resolution order:
 |      Apple
 |      Fruits
 |      **builtins.object
```

It's showing the inheritance order. That means `Apple` inherits from `Fruits`, which inherits from `object`

Comment: @ The Thonnu I got it thanks. I have one more question. Does all predefined classes also inherits from it ? Like <class int>, <class str> etc..

Comment: @AliMurtaza - yes. Every class, including built-in ones, inherits from it.

Comment: And, don't forget to accept the answer when you can!

Comment: For extra fun, all *classes* are of type `type`, and `type` is itself a subclass of class `object`, while also being the type of `object`. `type.__base__ is object` and `object.__class__ is type`. And `type(type) is type`. The top of the hierarchy is *weird*. :-)

Comment: Also note: `object` is the common base in Python 3, but in Python 2 (should you ever be unfortunate enough to need to maintain ancient code) user-defined classes are not automatically subclasses of `object`. If you don't have `__metaclass__ = type` in your file before the class definition, and you don't inherit from `object` or one of its subclasses (including all built-in types) explicitly, you get an old-style class, that follows a completely different framework. It's a mess. Python 3 made everything new-style to remove the weirdness the old system involved.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this is showing you that this class is of type object from the [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) of Python.

For some additional information:

```
Method resolution order:
 |      Apple
 |      Fruits
 |      **builtins.object
```

What it is fully telling you is that the inheritance order of this class will first resolve methods of the Apple class, if a method is called; then, if it can't resolve it in the Apple class (i.e. it doesn't exist) it'll look for it and resolve it based on definitions in the Fruits class and, lastly, look for it in **builtins.object, which is the archetype for all objects in Python.